# My "If" statement doesn't work in dart/flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an if statement in futureBuilder and it doesn't return something.
Plus that my futureBuilder it doesn't have model and you shouldn't define a model for it.
when my code is true, it will send a code for a mobile number and after that it doesn't navigate to another page.
Here it is:

```
onTap: () {
                                      final ID = _controller.text;
                                      final url = "https://************/api/User/CheckHasUser?id=$ID";
                                      Future fetchLogin() async {
                                        final response = await http.get(url);
                                        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                          return jsonDecode(response.body);
                                        } else {
                                          throw Exception('Failed');
                                        }
                                      }
                                      var Id = ID != null ? true : false;
                                      FutureBuilder(
                                        future: fetchLogin(),
                                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                                          if(Id == true){
                                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => getCodePage(),
                                            ));
                                          }else{
                                            print('s');
                                          }
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FutureBuilder is a Widget for reacting on Future results or showing a loading animation while waiting for it. Its builder-Function should return a Widget depending on the snapshot. But your FutureBuilder is not anywhere in the Widget tree so it is not built and does nothing.
If you just want to react on the completion of a Future and its result, use `fetchLogin().then(...)` instead.

EDIT:
Your code without FutureBuilder:

```
    final ID = _controller.text;
    final url = "https://************/api/User/CheckHasUser?id=$ID";
    Future fetchLogin() async {
        final response = await http.get(url);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           return jsonDecode(response.body);
        } else {
           throw Exception('Failed');
        }
   }
   var Id = ID != null;
   fetchLogin().then((resultOfFuture){
     if(Id){
        Navigator.of(context).push(
           MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => getCodePage(),
           ));
        }else{
           print('s');
        }
     }
   );
```

I hope this helps you further :)

Comment: thank you so much but would you please give a example on my code?

Comment: Thank you again, I have another question. what is that "resaultofFuture"? it returns just FALSE for me.

Comment: resultOfFuture is the result of your Future. So in your example the result of jsonDecode(response.body) if the statusCode is 200.